# Функция шаблонизатор при повторном использование с тем же шаблоном но с разными параметрами нечего не возвращает

Tags: php

Использую свою функцию для буферизации и вывода шаблонов.

Если использовать повторно с разными шаблонами возвращает ожидаемый результат, а если вызывать с одним файлом шаблона, но с разными параметрами, то при повторном запуске ничего не возвращает.

сама функция

```
function renderTemplate($template, $data) {
  if (file_exists($template)) {
    ob_start();
    require_once($template);
    return ob_get_clean();
  } else {
    return 'template not found';
  }
}
```

`renderTemplate($template1, $data1)` - вернет нужный результа

повторный вызов `renderTemplate($template1, $data2)` - ничего не вернет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделайте функцию таким образом

```
function renderTemplate($template, $data) {
  if (file_exists($template)) {
    ob_start();
    require($template);
    return ob_get_clean();
  } else {
    return 'template not found';
  }
}
```

Дело в том что надо использовать `include` или `require` вместо `include_once` или `require_once` так как последние не позволяют во время выполнения скрипта подключить 2 раза один и тот же файл.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!